problem send request with python requests library
I can not send request with this python code:
import requests

url = "http://139.248.156.245/test.php"
response = requests.get(url,timeout = 120)
print(response.text)

I am using ubuntu vps.
not any answer returned while I have no problem to send request with curl in the terminal.
curl "http://139.248.156.245/test.php"


what happens when the code is run ? (both  python and curl) , show results not 'I can not send request...', is not helpful

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

curl uses different header User-Agent - and for some portals this makes big difference, Maybe first use both with url https://httpbin.org/get and it will send you back all your headers and data - and you may compare curl with python
